# ECDsa in .Net Core throwing Invalid public key signature error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, ecdsa

I am following these docs to update SXGs (Signed Exchange).

https://github.com/google/webpackager/blob/main/docs/update_cache_api.md

I have generated the EC Public/Private Key pairs using below commands (as described in the docs):

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -out ecprivkey.pem
openssl ec -in ecprivkey.pem -pubout -out ecpubkey.pem
```

I have below .Net Core code, equivalent to whats described in doc, to use the above generated Private Key to create signature and send delete request:

**Code in docs:**

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="https://example.com/document"
CURL_URL="https://example-com.webpkgcache.com/doc/-/s/example.com/document"
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s)
MESSAGE=$({ \
  echo -n $URL; \
  echo -n " "; \
  echo -n $TIMESTAMP; })
SIGNATURE=$( \
  echo -n $MESSAGE | openssl dgst -sign ecprivkey.pem | base64 -w0)
curl \
-X DELETE \
--data-urlencode "timestamp=$TIMESTAMP" \
--data-urlencode "signature=$SIGNATURE" \
$CURL_URL
```

**My code in .Net Core**

```
            string timestamp = ((int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds).ToString();
            string message = url + " " + timestamp;
            string signature = "";

            using (ECDsa ecDsa = ECDsa.Create())
            {
                string key = File.ReadAllText(ecprivkeyPath);
                ecDsa.ImportFromPem(key);
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                byte[] signatureBytes = ecDsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
            }
                            
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("timestamp", timestamp),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("signature", signature),
            });

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, sxgURL)
            {
                Content = content
            };

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request))
            {
                var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if ((int)response.StatusCode == 202)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

But I am receiving below error:

```
"{\"error\":true,\"reason\":\"Invalid public key signature. Update cache denied.\"}"
```

Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: At least one difference between both codes is that *openssl dgst* returns an ECDSA signature in ASN.1/DER format, while `SignData()` uses the IEEE P1363 format by default. As of .NET 5 the format can be specified (via `DSASignatureFormat`).

Comment: Thank you so much Tapaco, and just to confirm for ASN.1/DER we should use  DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence, correct? with this format, I no longer see the error, but as per the documentation the api should return HTTP 202 response. But in my case its 200.

Comment: Yes, the ASN.1/DER ECDSA format is called `Rfc3279DerSequence` in .NET. Why 200 instead of 202 I don't know (but 200 doesn't seem to be a disadvantage, [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-successful-2xx)).